# Kotlin: Pass ranges in function as arguments

Tags: kotlin

Hello is it possible to pass range in Kotlin function just like in python?
I've just started learning Kotlin but I am a little bit stuck

I wish i could pass somethind like

```
my_gauge = Gauge('test_name',1..200, 201..300, and etc.)
```

for example I have a Gauge object which rotates on the base

```
class Gauge(val gauge_name: String,
            val red_value: Float, 
            val orange_value: Float,
            val yellow_value: Float,
            val green_value: Float,
            var current_value: Float,
            val min_value: Float,
            val max_value: Float) {

    val gauge_green = 0xFF66C2A5.toInt()
    val gauge_yellow = 0xFFFDD448.toInt()
    val gauge_orange = 0xFFF5A947.toInt()
    val gauge_red = 0xFFD53E4F.toInt()

    val min_rotation: Int = 0;
    val max_rotation: Int = 300;
    val ratio = max_rotation / max_value;

    fun calculate_rotation(): Int {
        return (current_value * ratio).toInt()
    }

    fun get_color(): Int {
        if (current_value >= red_value) {
            return gauge_red
        }
        if (current_value > orange_value) {
            return gauge_orange
        }

        if (current_value > yellow_value) {
            return gauge_yellow
        }

        return gauge_green
    }


}
```

I've just realized that it wont work with this data instead it will be better to build my logic around ranges

So my question is How to pass ranges as a param in class/function (instead of floats)

PS: The function `get_colors` is not correct I will fix it once I can pass ranges with `when(current_value)` statement

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, the type of a range produced by `..` is `ClosedRange<T>`:

```
fun foo(floatRange: ClosedRange<Float>) {
    println(floatRange.random())
}

// Usage:
foo(1f..10f)
```

For integer ranges, you may prefer `IntRange` over `ClosedRange<Int>` because it allows you to use it without the performance cost of boxing by using `first` and `last` instead of `start` and `endInclusive`. There is no unboxed version for other number types.

Comment: See what's "boxing": https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html

Answer (score 5):

**Try this in simple way, you can use range according to data type IntRange, FloatRange, LongRange etc.**

```
fun foo(range: IntRange){
    for (a in range){
        println(a)
    }
}
```

// call this function by
foo(1..10)

Comment: I Prefer Tenfour04's way he explained it much better tnx, for the contribution though :)